table-hover de Bootstrap deja de funcionar al eliminar todos los renglones de una tabla y agregar nuevos
Buen día estimados, les explico mi problema a ver si me pueden ayudar.
Tengo un proyecto que usa Bootstrap v5. En el proyecto tengo una tabla a la que le apliqué la clase table-hover.
IMAGEN 1: Tabla con la clase: table-hover

Cuando la tabla inicia con renglones desde que se carga la página, el HOVER funciona sin problema.
El problema es que, en una parte de la página, tengo un botón que lo que hace es recargar datos vía AJAX para actualizar la lista de renglones de la tabla.
IMAGEN 2: Script que actualiza la tabla

Cuando la info de la tabla se actualiza, el hover deja de funcionar... ¿Algo estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias.

El código como texto, favor editar la pregunta y agregarlo

ya encontré el problema. Mi tabla cuenta con las secciones <thead> y <tbody> por alguna razón, la función insertRow de la tabla agrega una nueva fila pero a nivel thead. El Hover que asigna Bootstrap evidentemente es para el tbody por eso se perdía.
SOLUCIÓN
Agregué un ID al tbody de mi tabla y reemplacé el código de actualización de la tabla por la siguiente función.
    function FnPopulateData(oData) {
        var StrTabla = "TblSearchResults", StrTableBody = "TblBodySearch";
        var TblSearchResults = document.getElementById(StrTableBody);
        var oRow = "";

        FnClearTable(StrTabla);

        oData.forEach(function (item) {

            var oRow = "<tr>";
            oRow += "<td>" + item["value"] + "</td>";
            oRow += "<td>" + item["code"] + "</td>";
            oRow += "<td>" + item["text"] + "</td>";
            oRow += "</tr>";

            TblSearchResults.innerHTML += oRow;

        });
    }

Ahora funciona.
Saludos!
